# Error H10: Application Error on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I am new on working with Rails and Heroku. I tried pushing my app onto Heroku and the push was successful but for some reason I receive an application error on my Heroku Site:

```
"An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served."
```

Would be great if someone could help. Passing along some information about my app and the environment.

In my Gem file I have the following databases running:

```
group :development, :test do
gem "sqlite3", "~> 1.3.6"
end

group :production do 
gem 'pg'
end

group :assets do
gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'
gem 'therubyracer'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end
```

In the Database.yml the following databases are setup:

```
development:
adapter: sqlite3
database: db/development.sqlite3
pool: 5
timeout: 5000

test:
adapter: sqlite3
database: db/test.sqlite3
pool: 5
timeout: 5000

production:
adapter: sqlite3
database: db/production.sqlite3
pool: 5
timeout: 5000
```

To begin with I don't understand why the .yml file still shows Sqlite3 in the production server? Shouldn't it change to pgres. In the Heroku Logs this is the key error message that displays:

```
 2012-10-23T19:22:36+00:00 heroku[router]: Error H10 (App crashed) -> GET thawing-dusk-  8202.herokuapp.com/analysis dyno= queue= wait= service= status=503 bytes=
```

Hope someone can help me out with this!

Thanks,

Comment: The .yml file has no effect when you push to heroku. It will replace it with its own after you push up. I have to admit I'm not sure of where you can look until you post up a full stack trace. You can look at the logs using the command `heroku logs` or you can even try accessing the console and see if you get a trace that way `heroku run console`. One other thing you can try is to run the rails app in production locally and see if works.

Comment: run heroku rake db migrate

Answer (score 1):

Your Rails application is most likely raising an exception upon startup from your source files.

This exception may not be obvious in the development environment because Rails doesn't eagerly load files in development or testing. However, when the production environment causes the Rails application to eagerly load all of the source files, the exception interrupts the application startup process and the application crashes with a lacking stack trace on the Heroku logs.

To come upon an informative stack trace, access the Rails console from your terminal running `heroku run rails c`, assuming you have the Heroku Toolbelt included and configured with your project. This will also fail on startup, as you are accessing the production environment, but the stack trace will be more extensive than the Heroku logs.

An alternative approach to diagnosing the problem would be to set the development environment to eager load source files.

```
# config/environments/development.rb
Rails.application.configure do

  config.eager_load = true

end
```

Finally, the best solution to this problem would be to review your test suite, if any, to include test cases that verify the source file's functionality.

Answer (score 0):

check is there any process which takes more than 30 seconds, if yes then your app will crashed with H10 error.